# How to select duplicate rows with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subtraction, divide

I have a dataframe like this:

```
import pandas as pd
dic = {'A':[100,200,250,300],
       'B':['ci','ci','po','pa'],
       'C':['s','t','p','w']}
df = pd.DataFrame(dic)
```

My goal is to separate the row in 2 dataframes:

- df1 = contains all the rows that do not repeat values along column `B` (unque rows).
- df2 = containts only the rows who repeat themeselves.

The result should look like this:

```
df1 =      A  B C         df2 =     A  B C
      0  250 po p               0  100 ci s 
      1  300 pa w               1  250 ci t
```

Note:

- the dataframes could be in general very big and have many values that repeat in column B so the answer should be as generic as possible

  - if there are no duplicates, df2 should be empty! all the results should be in df1

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) with parameter `keep=False` to create a mask for all duplicates and then [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), `~` to invert the `mask`:

```
mask = df.B.duplicated(keep=False)
print (mask)
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
Name: B, dtype: bool

print (df[mask])
     A   B  C
0  100  ci  s
1  200  ci  t

print (df[~mask])
     A   B  C
2  250  po  p
3  300  pa  w
```

Comment: The answer is quite good but it is not generic enough since if there are no duplicates, I get df[mask] as full. I will update the question.

Comment: I don't understand what's your problem with this answer, even looking at your update to your original question

Comment: @FedericoGentile - Do you think test if dataframe is empty? `if df2.empty:
    print ('empty')
else:
    print ('not empty')`

Comment: No problem, I already found my issue... the answer is perfect... I just called a variable with another name and I had weird results

Comment: How would you ignore `Nan` and `null` during the `duplicated`?

Comment: @Superdooperhero - Can you explain more? Something like `df.B.duplicated(keep=False) | df.B.isna()` ?

Comment: @jezrael I don't want to know about `Nan` duplicates. So ignore rows where the column that is duplicated has `Nan`.

Comment: @Superdooperhero - OK, then `df.B.duplicated(keep=False) & df.B.notna()` should working