# Print duplicates with one value changed

Tags: python, dataframe

I'm developing a student project about data analysis and I want to find all of the duplicates in the data frame, but with one specific cell changed e.g.

| Id | Name | Surname | Job | Wage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Black | Artist | 1200 |
| 2 | Adam | Smith | Artist | 1400 |
| 3 | John | Black | Artist | 1900 |
| 4 | John | Black | Driver | 1200 |
| 5 | Adam | Smith | Artist | 1400 |
| 6 | Adam | Black | Driver | 1200 |

and now I'd like to receive person with the same name, surname and job but with different salary or the same. It should look like this:

| Id | Name | Surname | Job | Wage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Black | Artist | 1200 |
| 3 | John | Black | Artist | 1900 |
| 2 | Adam | Smith | Artist | 1400 |
| 5 | Adam | Smith | Artist | 1400 |

(It's only simple data, I've got much, much more rows and columns).
How could I get this? I've tried with code like this:

```py
names=df['Name'].value_counts()
surnames=df['Surname'].value_counts()
jobs=df['Job'].value_counts()
wages=df['Wage'].value_counts()
for i in names:
    for j in surnames:
       for k in jobs:
            if (df['Name'] == i and df['Surname'] == j and df['Job'] == k):
                  print ("something")
```

but I still have   an error:

```
f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

also I've tried with lambda expression:

```py
for i in names:
    for j in surnames:
       for k in jobs:
           persons= df.apply(lambda x: print (x) if x['Name'] == i and x['Surname'] == j and x['Job'] == l else False, axis=1)

print(persons)
```

But I get pairs of id and value true or false. How could I repair it? Or what should I do? Thank you in advice

Comment: What if 3rd row was John Black Driver 1200 and 4th row as John Black Artist 1900. Do you want John Black Driver 1200 to be part of the result set and exclude John Black Artist 1900 ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select duplicate rows with pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41042996/how-to-select-duplicate-rows-with-pandas).  This was already asked. Please review the link for more details and options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all the duplicate records and non-duplicate records, you can use  `Series.duplicated` with parameter `keep=False`. It will result in a `boolean index`. You can then use the result to select rows you need.

The single line answer for your question is:

```
df[(df[['Name','Surname','Job']].duplicated(keep=False))]
```

The output is:

```
   Id  Name Surname     Job  Wage
0   1  John   Black  Artist  1200
1   2  Adam   Smith  Artist  1400
2   3  John   Black  Artist  1900
4   5  Adam   Smith  Artist  1400
```

Here's how it works:

For a dataframe as shown below:

```
>>> df
   Id  Name Surname     Job  Wage
0   1  John   Black  Artist  1200
1   2  Adam   Smith  Artist  1400
2   3  John   Black  Artist  1900
3   4  John   Black  Driver  1200
4   5  Adam   Smith  Artist  1400
5   6  Adam   Black  Driver  1200
```

Searching for duplicates of Name, Surname, and Job will result in:

```
>>> df[['Name','Surname','Job']].duplicated(keep=False)
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4     True
5    False
dtype: bool
```

With this boolean index, you can get all records that are True and False.

To get all the duplicates, you can give this command:

```
>>> df[(df[['Name','Surname','Job']].duplicated(keep=False))]
   Id  Name Surname     Job  Wage
0   1  John   Black  Artist  1200
1   2  Adam   Smith  Artist  1400
2   3  John   Black  Artist  1900
4   5  Adam   Smith  Artist  1400
```

To get all the non-duplicates, you can give this command. The `~` will negate and give you all the values that do not meet this criteria.

```
>>> df[~(df[['Name','Surname','Job']].duplicated(keep=False))]
   Id  Name Surname     Job  Wage
3   4  John   Black  Driver  1200
5   6  Adam   Black  Driver  1200
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use only `pandas` functions to filter dublicated records

```py
# group by columns
df_group = df.groupby(['Name', 'Surname', 'Job'])

# get group index size
df_group_size = df_group.size()

# filter on groups, get only duplications
df_group_more = df_group_size[df_group_size > 1]

# filter on main dataframe
filtered = df[df.apply(lambda r:(r['Name'], r['Surname'], r['Job']) in df_group_more.index, axis=1)]

print(filtered)
```

Output

```
   Id  Name Surname     Job  Wage
0   1  John   Black  Artist  1200
1   2  Adam   Smith  Artist  1400
2   3  John   Black  Artist  1900
4   5  Adam   Smith  Artist  1400
```